# react-native-async-storage/async-storage for that but it is not working

Tags: android, node.js, typescript, react-native, asyncstorage

**I am listing data in a contact list via Google Sheets API in a React Native (TypeScript) application. It works well. It needs to work offline. I have used react-native-async-storage/async-storage for that but it is not working.
Can you help me by looking at the code below?

https://github.com/premathunga/share/blob/main/App.tsx

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.